# Carroll's GR: The Schwarzschild Metric

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, symmetry, tensor-calculus, curvature

On page 195 of Sean M Carroll's *An Introduction to Special Relativity: Spacetime and Geometry*, he calculates the Christoffels and Riemann tensors for a generic metric that is static and has spherical symmetry. While doing so, it turns out that the only non zero Riemann tensors are those of the form $$R^\mu_{\, \, \nu \mu \nu}$$ and the non-zero Ricci tensors are of the form $$R_{\mu \mu}$$

I wanted to know if this additional symmetry in the indices of the Riemann and Ricci tensor were a result of the metric being static and spherically symmetric; and if so, why this should show up as a symmetry in indices in these tensors.

Comment: Isn't a static spacetime *always*  spherical symmetric?